# Displaying image URL from DB results

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this code in my Laravel site:

```
$postuser = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $fora->user_id)->get();
```

On my localhost when I request this:

```
{{$postuser[0]->img}}
```

It works and gives me img url. But when I put it online I get this error:

```
Undefined offset: 0 (View:
/home/****/public_html/*****/belezka/app/views/domov.blade.php
------------------------------------------------------------------------

)
```

Comment: may be your accessing an empty array.

Comment: as @dakine said, check that the $postuser object that's being returned is actually an instance of User. Localhost vs "online" could be that your database isn't populated. Also if you're expecting only one result (or no result) from a query, consider using ->first() instead of ->get().  It saves you from having to muck around with a single-element array.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
 $postusers = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $fora->user_id)->get();
 return View::make('(your_view)', compact('postusers'));
```

In your view:

```
 @foreach($postusers as $postuser)
   {{$postuser->img}}
 @endforeach
```